# Как обновить время в БД без потери прошлого прогресса времени

Tags: c#, discord, entity-framework-core

Я хочу сделать чтобы дискорд бот мог записывать время пользователя проведенного в голосовом канале у меня получилось, чтобы бот записывал время когда пользователь заходит в голосовой канал и когда выходит из него но у меня проблема если ещё раз зайти в голосовой канал у меня время обнуляется и всё идет по новой  вот как происходит запись времени в БД

```
 public static async Task StartTimeUsr(Usr user)
        {
            using var DbContext = new SqlDbContext();
            DbContext.Update(user);
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Comment: например, сохранять время не в одном поле, а в таблице событий, где для каждого действия будет своя запись (зашел/вышел) и потом на основании этих данных можно будет считать, например, общее время, получится некий event sourcing

Comment: @ExplodingKitten чесно говоря бред, чтобы создавались новые ячейки в бд потом их всех суммировать вообще даже не хочу об этом писать, можно как-то таймер поместить в ячейку чтобы он срабатывал когда юзер заходит в войс канал и останавливался когда выходит это же как по мне самый идеальный вариант

Comment: Ну вообще то это не бред, а повсеместная практика логирования и учета. У вас в таблице будет запись входа, запись выхода, других действий если надо, и вы при помощи этой статистике сможете сделать многое. Ну а так, отвечая на ваш вопрос про таймер: Скажите, если у вас в кармане, на листочке, будет написано текущее время, после того как вы достанете этот листок, время будет текущее, или то, что вы записали ранее? Ну вот также и база, она предназначена для хранения данных, а не для подсчетов или чего-либо еще, да, там есть процедуры, но это другое.

Comment: `если ещё раз зайти в голосовой канал у меня время обнуляется и всё идет по новой`. Ничего не понял. Что значит "время обнуляется и все идет по новой"? Вы хотели сказать "время захода и выхода затираются новыми значениями, из-за чего удаляются предыдущие данные"?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko да

Comment: Если вы хотите хранить время захода и ухода предыдущих сессий, то создайте отдельную таблицу `userChannelHistory`, где будет храниться `sessionId` (уникальное id записи таблицы), `userId` (ForeignKey), `channelId` (если вам нужно следить за несколькими каналами), `timeEntered`, `timeLeaved`. Это, кстати, по сути тоже самое, что предлагал пользователь @ExplodingKitten